# statically linking c file with android bionic c library

Tags: android, c, makefile, bionic

I just wrote a small c file and its header file.
dev_access.c and dev_access.h

I want to link it to the bionic library in android and create a statically/dynamically linked archive file.

My files are in /home/preetam/mydev/
The android sources are in /home/preetam/android_source

The following is my current makefile

```
CROSS           := /home/preetam/bin/CodeSourcery/arm2010/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi
CC              := $(CROSS)-gcc
INC_DIR         := /home/preetam/android_source/bionic/libc
CFLAGS          := -Wall -c -I$(INC_DIR)/include

android_hal: dev_access.o
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} dev_access.c -o dev_access.a

clean:
        rm -f *.o dev_access.a
```

I am not sure whats going wrong but header files are not linking and some missing and redefinition errors are coming up.
The following is the Console output:

```
/home/preetam/bin/CodeSourcery/arm2010/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -Wall -I/home/preetam/android_source/bionic/libc/include -static   -c -o dev_access.o dev_access.c
In file included from /home/preetam/android_source/bionic/libc/include/stdio.h:42,
                 from dev_access.c:1:
/home/preetam/android_source/bionic/libc/include/sys/_types.h:40: fatal error: machine/_types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [dev_access.o] Error 1
```

First of all, Is my Makefile correct?
Whats the proper way to link your programs with bionic libc ?
How to make the final object an archive?

Comment: I think you need ar to bundle dev_access.o into a lib dev_access.a

Comment: ar libdev_access.a dev_access.o

Comment: I am not able to get make to compile. I am not sure what needs to be included. Also I am not sure if I need the compiled bionic or if the source will suffice.

Comment: This error seems to be coming from the include of stdio.h itself.

Comment: You need to find machine/...  and put it in your include path.

Comment: You should be using these include paths:

libc/arch-$ARCH/include
      libc/include
      libc/kernel/common
      libc/kernel/arch-$ARCH

Comment: Including the machine folder is creating lots of redefinition errors among the include files.

Comment: I managed to get a compiles libc.a. Can you tell me how to statically link with it. please give me make commands for it.

Comment: Thanks for the list of files to include. As it turns out, I had left out the common and kernel/arch-arm. As I have cross compiled for arm, the 'ar' command is not working. Gives out 'ar: invalid option --e' But I actually used the same command without any arguments. Did not pass -e at all.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for all the help. I finally got it.

Comment: Good job! Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using these include paths for bionic:

```
libc/arch-$ARCH/include 
libc/include 
libc/kernel/common 
libc/kernel/arch-$ARCH
```

ar might have some switches for it...

EDIT: The switch is cr

```
ar -crv <libname> <source_object>
```